# The JVM's JIT arg "-XX:CompileCommand=exclude" is not effective

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I used the following JVM arguments in my Java 17 application:

```bash
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/alibaba/fastjson/parser/JSONLexerBase::scanSymbol \
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/alibaba/fastjson/parser/SymbolTable::addSymbol
```

But this method was still compiled by C2 compiler. I found the JIT compilation by JFR:

```
Event Thread        Method
C2 CompilerThread0  String com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.SymbolTable.addSymbol(char[], int, int, int)
```

how can I prevent JIT compilation for specified methods?

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax. See the output of `java -XX:CompileCommand=help`. You either need to use `package/Class.method()` or `package.Class::method()`, but you're mixing those two syntaxes (and forgetting the signature, but some sources suggest it's optional).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you're right!  Sometimes these subtle issues are indeed not easy to detect, especially when the JVM does not provide any error messages.